# File notify watcher not getting triggered when inside Tauri setup

Tags: rust, inotify, file-watcher, tauri

I'm trying to add a [notify](https://crates.io/crates/notify) to a basic [Tauri](https://tauri.app) app. The notify watcher seems to work outside the Tauri setup (`watcher1`) but not inside the Tauri setup (`watcher2`).

```rust
use notify::{RecursiveMode, Result, Watcher};
use std::path::Path;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut watcher1 = notify::recommended_watcher(move |res| match res {
        Ok(event) => {
            // does get printed
            println!("watcher1 event: {:?}", event);
        }
        Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e),
    })
    .expect("error creating file watcher");

    watcher1
        .watch(Path::new("."), RecursiveMode::Recursive)
        .expect("error watching folder");

    tauri::Builder::default()
        .setup(|_app| {
            let mut watcher2 = notify::recommended_watcher(move |res| match res {
                Ok(event) => {
                    // does not get printed
                    println!("watcher2 event: {:?}", event);
                }
                Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e),
            })
            .expect("error creating file watcher");

            watcher2
                .watch(Path::new("."), RecursiveMode::Recursive)
                .expect("error watching folder");

            Ok(())
        })
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri builder");

    Ok(())
}
```

You can get the full code here: https://github.com/kasbah/tauri-notify . You should be able to clone that and run `yarn && yarn tauri dev`, then go into `src-tauri` and change some files, e.g. `touch random-file && rm random-file`.

- I can remove `watcher1` and I'm still not seeing any `watcher2` events so they don't seem to be conflicting with each other.
- If I add `println!("watcher2: {:?}", watcher2);` it does seem to getting created alright.

Comment: `watcher2` gets destroyed when setup finishes while `watcher1` is still alive.

Comment: (I thought I replied before!) That makes sense, thanks.